# Using custom function as parameter for another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently dealing with refactoring my code, and trying to automate AJAX requests as follows:

The goal is to have a context-independent function to launch AJAX requests. The data gathered is handled differently based on the context.

This is my function:

```
function ajaxParameter(routeName, method, array, callback){

//Ajax request on silex route
var URL = routeName;

 $.ajax({
  type: method,
  url: URL,
  beforeSend: function(){
    DOM.spinner.fadeIn('fast');
  },
})
.done(function(response) {
    DOM.spinner.fadeOut('fast');

    callback(response);

 })
 .fail(function(error){
    var response = [];
    response.status = 0;
    response.message = "Request failed, error : "+error;
    callback(response);
 })
}
```

My problem essentially comes from the fact that my callback function is not defined. 
I would like to call the function as such (example)

```
ajaxParameter(URL_base, 'POST', dataBase, function(response){
    if(response.status == 1 ){
        console.log('Request succeeded');
    }
    showMessage(response);
});
```

I thought of returning response to a variable and deal with it later, but if the request fails or is slow, this won't work (because response will not have been set).

That version would allow me to benefit the `.done()` and `.fail()`.

EDIT : So there is no mistake, I changed my code a bit. The goal is to be able to deal with a callback function used in both `.done()` and `.fail()` context (two separate functions would also work in my case though).

Comment: Why not just use the `callback` within the `.fail()` method, as you have done with the `.done()` method?

Comment: You say your goal is to have a "context-independent function to launch AJAX requests". Is that not exactly what the `$.ajax` method is?

Comment: I'm confused as to what is wrong, if you call the ajaxParameter function using the anonymous function as in your example, it should work.

Comment: @shennan this is not exactly my problem, it doesn't work in the .done() either, and the goal would be to avoid having to repeat the code for the request. This should also interess @Yoda, my console tells me `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function`.

Comment: Have you tried isolating this specific code from the rest of your project and running it? I'm sure you will see that it works as in the js-fiddle provided by shennan. From there you can begin a process of elimination going through the call stack to determine where your bug really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see there really is nothing wrong with your script. I've neatened it up a bit here, but it's essentially what you had before:

```
function ajaxParameter (url, method, data, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(){

            DOM.spinner.fadeIn('fast');

        }
    })
    .done( function (response) {

        DOM.spinner.fadeOut('fast');

        if (callback)
            callback(response);

     })
     .fail( function (error){

        var response = [];

        response.status = 0;

        response.message = "Request failed, error : " + error;

        if (callback)
            callback(response);

     });
}
```

And now let's go and test it [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y85zdLvk/).

As you can see (using the JSFiddle AJAX API), it works. So the issue is probably with something else in your script. Are you sure the script you've posted here is the same one you are using in your development environment?

In regards to your error; be absolutely sure that you are passing in the right arguments in the right order to your `ajaxParameter` function. Here's what I am passing in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y85zdLvk/):

- the url endpoint (e.g http://example.com/)
- the method (e.g 'post')
- some data (e.g {foo:'bar'})
- the callback (e.g function(response){ };)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I use two scripts. First is a common dictionnary of functions (including ajaxParameter), and then each view has its own script (scripts are called in this order). The error shows up in the function definition. The function is called as such in my script : `ajaxParameter(
      URL_base, 
      'POST', 
      dataBase, 
      function(response){
                                console.log(response);
   },
   function(response){
    console.log(response);
   }
  );`

Comment: @PaulGabriel without more of an understanding of where your methods are being called, I cannot see why you should be getting an `Uncaught TypeError`. As far as I am concerned, you are passing a `function` as your `callback` argument. Is there a live url where your code is currently living? Or are you able to upload an example?

Comment: it would be possible to give you access but it is protected so I would need to contact you privately, if you're willing to help. For more details : it's a Symfony environment and I use Assetic to compile and link javascript files. The console error occurs even before the function is called, it happens when it is declared.

Comment: I'm unsure as to how we would go about contacting each other privately. Stack Overflow chat only allows members who have more than 20 reputation, which you currently don't have. In regards to your first comment, are you saying that the error happens when trying to call `ajaxParameter`? In which case, it sounds like you may have a scope issue. Can you confirm or disconfirm that the program (at the point you call your `ajaxParameter` function) knows what `ajaxParameter` is? Something like this `console.log(ajaxParameter)` maybe?

Comment: Actually the error happens when defining `ajaxParameter` , (it doesn't even go as far as calling it). If you have twitter could you tweet me at @PauulGabriel ?

Comment: @PaulGabriel please try copying my version of the function (in my answer) verbatim and do a wholesale replacement of your `ajaxParameter` function. What happens then?

Comment: I copied it strictly, and it is working. I seem to understand that the `if` test solved the problem. Anyway I really couldn't be more thankful, it's very nice of you to have taken so much time to help :)

Comment: @PaulGabriel It's possible that, in certain circumstances, if you fail to pass a callback function, it will be attempting to call an `undefined` variable. The `if` statement makes sure that there is indeed something to call, before it attempts to call it. Anyway, if this post has solved your problem then please mark it as correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this, passing the success and fail callbacks:

```
function ajaxParameter(routeName, method, array, success, failure) {

    //Ajax request on silex route
    var URL = routeName;

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: URL,
        beforeSend: function () {
            DOM.spinner.fadeIn('fast');
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
          DOM.spinner.fadeOut('fast');
          success(response);
    }).fail(function (error) {
          var response = [];
          response.status = 0;
          response.message = "Request failed, error : " + error;
          failure(response);
    })
}
```

Called like:

```
ajaxParameter(
   URL_base, 
   'POST',
   dataBase, 
   function(response){
       //success function
   }, 
   function(response){
       // fail function
   }
);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, unfortunately when I try with the "callback" parameter, my console tells me this `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function`